# unicorn/kgio LoadError in vagrant

Tags: unicorn, vagrant

I'm working through the railscasts tutorial on unicorn and nginx (http://railscasts.com/episodes/293-nginx-unicorn), using a lucid32 box in vagrant. My OS is Mountain Lion. I'm using rbenv and ruby 1.9.2p290. After adding unicorn to my Gemfile, and running bundle, I run:

```
bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -D
```

And this is the result:

```
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/kgio-2.8.0/lib/kgio.rb:21:in `require': /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/kgio-2.8.0/lib/kgio_ext.so: undefined symbol: rb_prohibit_interrupt - /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/kgio-2.8.0/lib/kgio_ext.so (LoadError)
from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/kgio-2.8.0/lib/kgio.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/unicorn-4.6.0/lib/unicorn.rb:6:in `require'
from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/unicorn-4.6.0/lib/unicorn.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/unicorn-4.6.0/lib/unicorn/launcher.rb:9:in `require'
from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/unicorn-4.6.0/lib/unicorn/launcher.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/unicorn-4.6.0/bin/unicorn:3:in `require'
from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/unicorn-4.6.0/bin/unicorn:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/unicorn:19:in `load'
from /opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/unicorn:19:in `<main>'
```

Any tips?

Comment: Does the lucid32 box still have ruby 1.8 installed? Maybe some kind of 1.8 incompatibility

Comment: rbenv is set to global 1.9.2-p290.